# Is it ldif or search filter?

Tags: java, ldap, ldif, apache-directory

I'm writing standalone java program where I pass input and output files as command line arguments. The input file contains either valid LDAP search filter or LDIF.

I'm using Apache Directory LDAP API but I've not found anything there I could use to distinguish between the two (filter|ldif). Nor have I found any useful examples online.

What would be the best way for me to distinguish between the two?

Any ideas or examples appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use .ldif file extensions for the LDIF files and then check the extension of the file in java?

Comment: Or pass a flag to your program indicating whether your file contains LDIF formatted data or an LDAP filter.

Comment: And in my code how would I distinguish between the two if I don't have the option of passing flag to my program when I run it?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the search-filter(s) as LDIF, too, so you don't have to deal with two different file formats.

Comment: And in my code how would I distinguish between the two if I'm unable to pass flag to my program?

Comment: How about introducing a special AttributeType? You are able to recognize something like query:(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(telephoneNumber=*)) in your own code, then.